# Задача на проценты codewars

Tags: c#, математика

Задача:

In a small town the population is p0 = 1000 at the beginning of a year. The population regularly increases by 2 percent per year and moreover 50 new inhabitants per year come to live in the town. How many years does the town need to see its population greater or equal to p = 1200 inhabitants?

Примеры:

```
nb_year(1500, 5, 100, 5000) -> 15
nb_year(1500000, 2.5, 10000, 2000000) -> 10
```

мой код которые работает неверное и в том месте где я привожу к int

```
private static int NbYear(int p0, double percent, int aug, int p)
        {
            int totalNumberOfYears = 0;
            while (p0 <= p)
            {
                p0 = p0 + p0 * (((int)percent) / 100) + aug;
                totalNumberOfYears++;
            }
            return totalNumberOfYears;
        }
```

Проблема:
Неверно считает количество лет, и как я понял ошибка в первой строке тела цикла, там произведение p0 на (((int)percent) / 100) получается 0, я пробовал убрать привидение типов и вместо 100 брал 100.0, но тоже не помогло, помогите пожалуйста

Comment: перечитайте свой вопрос хотя бы раз и попытайтесь понять в чем проблема и о чем он

Comment: @Эникейщик мне всё понятно, а вы вместо того чтобы "умничать" могли бы просто задать вопрос

Comment: "мой код которЫЕ работает НЕВЕРНОЕ и в том месте где я привожу к int" ... "это мои тестовые данные при вызове метода И Я ПОЧЕМУ-ТО ПОЛУЧАЮ но там где в скобках привожу к int". Собственно, о какой понятности может идти речь, где нет запятых, где все смешалось в одну кашу, и так далее? Будто пьяный человек пытается свою мысль донести. Пожалуйста, протрезвейте, и исправьте свой вопрос. Помните, что вы задаете его незнакомым людям, которые не знают вас, ваш проект, не знают что вы можете, и что вы делаете. Вот пойдите на улицу, найдите первого прохожего, и задайте ему этот вопрос, поймет? Нет..

Comment: Непонятно, все же, в чем суть вопроса?

Comment: что именно вам понятно в наборе слов "это мои тестовые данные при вызове метода и я почему-то получаю но там где в скобках привожу к int"?

Comment: @Эникейщик мне всё понятно, я же не умственно отсталый

Comment: "не умственно отсталые" люди улучшают вопрос, когда несколько человек пишут, что ничего не понятно. Но можешь и дальше убеждать всех, что все в этом тексте все понятно. Ты даже вопрос не осилил сформулировать, "не осталый" он... Ну или мы тут сами умственно отсталые, поэтому помочь тебе не сможем. Иди за помощью в другое место.

Comment: @Эникейщик я поправил немного вопрос, извините за охуевшее поведение, настроение такое по жизни

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я вообще не понимаю, зачем в коде цикл? Этого достаточно (правда, это C/C++, но не думаю, что это важно):

```
int NbYear(double p0, double percent, double aug, double p)
{
    percent /= 100.;
    return ceil(log((p+aug/percent)/(p0+aug/percent))/log(1+percent));
}
```

Comment: нет, разница есть и большая

Comment: В чем, если не секрет? Вы не в состоянии переписать это на C#?

Comment: секрет кроется в первой строчке цикла: p0 = p0 + p0 * (((int)percent) / 100) + aug, а конкретнее в месте где я p0 умножаю на  (((int)percent) / 100), в результате чего получаю ноль каким-то образом, пробовал убрать привидение типов и вместо 100 брать 100.0 тоже не помогло. помогите пожалуйста разобраться и ещё убрать минуса на вопросе, а то я новые не могу задавать

Comment: помогите пожалуйста убрать минуса на вопросе, я больше так не буду себя вести

Comment: У меня в решении нет никаких циклов :) И не надо пытаться работать с целыми числами там, где они не годятся. Я не зря использовал только `double`... К минусам я никакого отношения не имею, я не модератор (не уверен, кстати, что они могут убирать минусы), да и минус я не ставил.

Comment: понятно, спасибо, я тогда отмечу ваше решение как ответ хоть не сильно то и помогло

Comment: скажите, а с вами можно как-нибудь связаться и обсудить паттер repository и unit of work если вы знаете такие

Comment: Нет, не стоит. Есть ruSO, а вне его я мужик неотзывчивый, неразговорчивый и мрачный... Кстати, о помогло/не помогло... еще раз и медленно: ***Я не зря использовал только `double`*** Учитесь видеть то, что вам показывают!